# How can I format Flask Werkzeug logging or move the request values to my logger format?

Tags: python, flask, python-logging

I am pretty green to Flask but not Python.  I'm setting up my logging for my like so:

In logger.py:

```
logfile = f"{ basedir }/app.log"
log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - (%(threadName)-10s) - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(filename = logfile, format = log_format, level=logging.DEBUG)
log = logging.getLogger()
```

Then in each file:

```
from logger import log
log.debug("Oh no, the sky is falling!")
```

When my webapp gets an API call, it emits the following into the log:

```
2023-08-08 16:48:21,559 - INFO - (Thread-80 (process_request_thread)) - 111.222.333.444 - - [08/Aug/2023 16:48:21] "GET /v1/user/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The 1st half-ish is per my formatting.  Werkzeug adds additional info to the end of the line, which I've noted.  Note that the time/date is superfluous.  I like the IP and request information.

How can I either:

a. Format that Werkzeug output to remove the time/date and possibly
add additional meaningful values?

b. Just remove the Werkzeug output but add the IP and request info to the
normal logger output?

Answer (score 1):

Partially answering my own question....

You can't change werkzeug logs.  They are hardcoded in.  See [code here](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/72b2e48e7d44927b1b7d6b2f940d0691230de893/src/werkzeug/serving.py#L388).